# Azure Web Sites: Error connecting to Twilio "SSL certificate pro blem: unable to get local issuer certificate (0)"

Tags: php, azure, ssl, twilio

I forked the [GitHub OpenVBX project](https://github.com/twilio/OpenVBX), created an Azure Web Site (with MySQL on ClearDb), and configured it to pull from the fork. (Steps to reproduce are similar to:  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/create-a-php-web-site)

The site comes up and I'm able to configure it until it tries to connect to Twilio.

On the Connect to Twilio page, after entering the required fields, I get this error:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (0)

There is no errors in the web server logs or in my Twilio account logs.

The error doesn't give enough details about what it is doing to diagnose the issue.

I've posted this as an [issue](https://github.com/twilio/OpenVBX/issues/252) on the OpenVBX project site.

---

**Update:** I tried updating the cacert.pem file for CURL. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "twilio_use_certificate" to true in \config\config.php.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Use Twilio API Certificate
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Curl certificates on some systems are either incomplete or out of date and
| this can effect connectivity to the Twilio API. If you're getting an error
| "error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify 
| failed (0)" then set the option below to true.
|
*/
$config['twilio_use_certificate'] = true;
```